# Is there anyway to find last route's url in controller function of loading view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this 2 views with urls, [both share same controller/view]

```
example.com/default.aspx#/categories/2/products/100
example.com/default.aspx#/categories/2/sales/200
```

when I click back I go back to this url,

```
example.com/default.aspx#/categories/2
```

I want to know in categories controller constructor which route user is coming back from, whether it's products or sales ***from the URL***

This is because I have 2 accordion so I want to select them based on url.

Comment: You could acheive this using a variety of methods based on my assumptions of your code. Use ASP.NET sessions and mix in the JavaScript or use JavaScript history. Maybe post further code about your application as it looks like a poor idea so far to use # rather than solid parameter queryStrings

Comment: @Thalaivar it is angular, sry forgot 2 add

Comment: Why don't you just pass the information as a query string?

Comment: not sure whether this will help or not
`$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
          // here fromState will have the previous route details
      });`